# Is string comparison the right way to do dynamic styling for variants in React-JSS?

Tags: reactjs, jss

I have a Sandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/p2wy9pp8lx

I have some dynamic styling like this:

```
const styles = {
  fooDisplay: props => ({
    display: props.variant === "foo" ? "block" : "none"
  }),
}
```

For a class like:

```
const Something = ({ classes, children, variant }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.someThing}>
      <div> variant is : {variant}</div>
      <div className={classes.fooDisplay}>I only display if variant is foo</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This does what I want.

Is using string comparison the right way to achieve this though? Or would this be bad for performance?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in my opinion is to export variant constants on each element that you can reference whenever you import the element, an example would look like:

`<Button variant={Button.Variant.PRIMARY}> This is a primary button </Button>`

And on Button you can do a check using the same constants `this.props.variant === Variant.Primary`

There's no real performance issue with string comparison, it's just a weakly typed way of getting to the same solution, and looks a little bit messier. This method means there's no room for error and it's very clear what the intent is.

If you need a bit more code to understand what I mean let me know